# How to convert attachment pages to Posts?

Tags: posts, attachments

I have mp3 files as attachments, I would like to have each attachment page considered as posts, Is it even possible?.
Are there plugins that does it?.
Importantly, I need to use the id3v2 tags of the file as the post's content., with the ability to select some tag as post tags.

Comment: Attachments are already a post type ( attachment post type ) which can be viewed by accessing their page ( as far as I remember, e.g. example.com/?p=123, which 123 is the ID of the attachment ). You can check the media library to find which is the correct URL for viewing them. But what do you mean by converting them to posts? What should be the content of that post? Its title? and so on.

Comment: How to populate that attachment page with the file's meta data, in my case, populating the post content with id3v2 tags.